# How do I get a count of current operations in MongoDB 3.2

Tags: mongodb

I'd like to find the total number of current operations in MongoDB.  Something like:

`db.currentOp().count()`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`db.currentOp().inprog.length`

The `inprog` is an array of current operations